# Is it possible to use relative paths with PHP scandir and does authentication affect scandir?

Tags: php, authentication, relative-path, scandir

I have an authenticated directory in my site that has a bunch of directories of photos in it. If you log in you can access these photos.

```
/admin/galleries/
```

I want to build another page outside of that directory that I can grant guest access to viewing the list of directories in the authenticated directory.

```
/guest/access/
```

I just need a simple list of the directories in the `/admin/galleries/` dir. I'm trying to use scandir.

```
$folderlist = scandir("../../admin/galleries");
```

This doesn't return `false`, but it returns empty. I'm not sure why? Is it the authentication on that directory that's blocking access via scandir? I wouldn't have thought that would have affected a server process like scandir.

Is the relative path a problem? When I make a dummy directory inside of `/guest/access/` and change the scandir path to `scandir(".")`, it outputs that directory's name. But if I move that same directory up into the `/guest/` directory and change scandir to `scandir("..")` or `scandir("../../guest")`, it returns empty again. That makes me think it's *not* an authentication problem, but something with scandir itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to have left this question unanswered so long:

It wasn't returning empty, I just hadn't incorporated the correct relative path into my echo statements and had run them through an is_dir() statement that returned false because those directories didn't exist in the local directory. Dumb mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `dirname(__FILE__)` before your `/../../`